# Improve dataframe shift efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 118685 rows × 388 columns of dataframe `df`.
If I do a `df.shift(1)`, it takes a second to complete, is there a way to make it faster

Comment: All columns has same dtypes?

Comment: @jezrael nope, it has different dtypes

Comment: @jezrael to be exact, those are the different dtypes {dtype('bool'), dtype('<M8[ns]'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64')}

Comment: you can try, ```np.roll(df1,1, axis=0)``` if you are okay if result is numpy array

Comment: @DevKhadka - Just tested, it convert columns to object and also working different like shift.

Comment: `print (pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df,1, axis=0)).dtypes)`

Comment: ya it does but its columns can be used comparisons and conditions etc. if that is what the william007's intension. and it can be letter converted back to original datatype using df.astype(dict)
@william007 it will be easier if you can give little extra information on what you are trying to do